# Does Parse.com API's allow identifying a particular customer?

Tags: android, parse-platform

How can I use Parse.com android API's to identify a particular user ? Flurry allows using `FlurryAgent.setUserId`, Crittercism allows using `Crittercism.setUsername(`. What does `Parse.` have ?

**Possible Solution**
Will this work ?

```
Parse.initialize(this, "asdfasdfs", "asdfasd");
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
ParseInstallation.create(identity == null ? "No Identity Set"
            : identity);
```

Comment: If you mean uniquely identifying each user or any other object, Parse has it's default `objectId` for every object you create, including user objects. It even has it's own default user class: `PFUser`.

Comment: I need to identify each user. So that I can address a message to that particular user. For exmaple, I know his app crashed, I want to reassure him that we have seen it and will fix it.

Comment: Yup, the User's `objectId`. But not sure if a particular user's details are attached to crash reports.

Comment: Yes Crittercism does allow it with setUserName. Please put an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse has a default User class which has two unique fields: `objectId` and `username`. (The User class also has fields such as `email`, `password` out of the box).

You can use either the `objectId` or `username` to query for a specific user.

`ParseInstallation` is a class which stores the installation details of your app for the user. There will be an installation object per device. This is usually used for push notifications and managing sessions or you can use it for device specific tasks (again, messages).

The installation object is created when a user is created/ signed up from a device. Since it is a subclass of `ParseObject` (or `PFObject` on iOS), you can store your own fields of data on it if needed.

[Documentation for `ParseUser`](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#users)